# What is the final product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: final product]

According to the first step,nbs performs allylic bromination,replacing one H from -Ch3 group. Now,as iodine is strongly bonded to the ring due to resonance,CH3SNa replaces Br and forms NaBr as an additional product
My final answer comes out to be A,but the given answer is None of the above. What will then be the final product?

Comment: It would be good if the NBS equivalents and conditions were given, but I think you are correct that A is the expected product. Query this with your tutor

Comment: Usually, Such MCQs provided by Indian authors don't have much details of conditions or solvents or any such extra but important details. In this question, it isn't mentioned that with addition of NBS, heat or light is provided or not, so it may or may not be a radical reaction.

Comment: I think you are meant to think it is not a radical reaction as there is no initiator mentioned, either chemical or light. Hence, the assumption would be that NBS is acting as an electrophile.  Not ideal without conditions being supplied but there you go.